# I use google api translate api get chinese character, but I don't know how to convert into words

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, python-unicode

I use google translate api, get simple Chinese words; 
but they only shows like this: '\u6211\u7684\u540d\u5b57\u53eb\u6770\u592b',
I know this is Unicode, so I use .encode('utf-8'), not working.
Do anybody have methods to let it show words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run python console:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug  2 2016, 14:18:34) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> words = '\u6211\u7684\u540d\u5b57\u53eb\u6770\u592b'
>>> words
'我的名字叫杰夫'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I know what's issue I use windows console, so interesting, windows console not working, but python console works. Thank you turkus.

Comment: @yiwang set my answer as solving your problem please, you can help me in this way :) Thanks!